# How to get URL from the currently opened browser in MFC application?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, visual-c++, mfc

I am working on an application where
I need URL from currently opened browser.

I have tried one code from following link
[to get URL from the current opened browser](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176792) but it is not working.

can anyone tell me a simple approach to do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can't just say " it is not working". Please give some details.

Comment: @manuell this problem has been solved by trying the same code and editing some changes in it. the problem was i have not called the **QueryInterface** methods for each objects such as 'hR = m_spSHWinds->Item(va, &spDisp);
IWebBrowser2 *spBrowser = NULL;
hR =spDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void**)&spBrowser);'